# signed applet doesn't work on browser

Tags: java, security, clojure, applet, japplet

I have an applet that reads from the microphone with that code

```
(defn mic []
  (let [info (DataLine$Info.
              (get-class)
              (get-format))
        line (AudioSystem/getLine info)
        out (ByteArrayOutputStream.)]
    (.open line)
    (.start line)))
```

it is signed with "$ jarsigner name-of-project-X.X.X-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar seesaw"  but it still fails to open from browser
When i grant "record" permission(java.policy file) and open it with appletviwer it works perfectly.
how can i get it work within the browser without a policy file?

Comment: yous should post your exact error and what permissions you are asking for in the manifest file.